# Change one particular bin colour in a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization, seaborn

Im making a bar chart using the command .plot(kind = "bar") of Fortune 500 Companies by Country. While i get a barchart , i just want to highlight the bins that give , me the number of companies from China and US that made it to 500 to better highlight the difference. Is there anyway to just differently colour those two  bins to make them stand out  ?

Answer (score 2):

With pandas' `df.plot(kind='bar')` you probably need to set the colors by iterating through the generated bars. With seaborn you could set them directly:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

countries = ['China', 'India', 'United States', 'Indonesia', 'Pakistan', 'Brazil', 'Nigeria', 'Bangladesh', 'Russia', 'Mexico']

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': countries,
                   'number': np.random.randint(10, 30, len(countries))})
colors = ['dodgerblue' if cntry == 'United States' else
          'limegreen' if cntry == 'China' else
          'turquoise' for cntry in df['country']]
sns.barplot(x='country', y='number', data=df, palette=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

To achieve something similar with pandas, and supposing no other "patch" elements are drawn onto the same subplot:

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
for bar, color in zip(ax.patches, colors):
    bar.set_color(color)
```

Note that pandas does allow providing multiple colors to `df.plot(kind='bar')` when multiple dataframe columns are plotted. So one color for each plotted column.